# What is the best way to remove a stack view with arranged subviews inside?

Tags: ios, swift

I made a vertical stack view with some buttons inside where the user can toggle between some controls: So when the user toggles the **triggerMarkersBtn** a vertical stack view with 2 controls is added to the **sourceView**.

```
let stackView = UIStackView()
   @objc func handleMarkers(sender: UIButton) {
       let triggerMarkersBtn = sender
       if let sourceView = self.view {
            sourceView.addSubview(stackView)
            stackView.axis = .vertical
            stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: triggerMarkersBtn.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filterSectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: triggerMarkersBtn.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
            stackView.spacing = 2.0
            
            let activateMarker = UIButton()
            activateMarker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(activateMarker(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(activateMarker)

            let deactivateMarker = UIButton()
            deactivateMarker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deactivateMarker(sender:)), for: 
.touchUpInside)
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(deactivateMarker)
}
}
```

My problem is that I want to remove the stack view from its superview when the user selects a button inside of it. So in the button target something like: ***removeFromSuperView()*** and ***remvoeArrangedSubviews(view:)***. I also tried changing the stack views visibility..
Unluckily all arranged subviews are added to the stack view again and again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create buttons and place the `stackView` inside your `sourceView` each time the `handleMarkers` method is fired. Set it up once as a lazy var:

```swift
    private lazy var markersStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 2.0
        
        let activateMarker = UIButton()
        activateMarker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(activateMarker(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(activateMarker)
        
        let deactivateMarker = UIButton()
        deactivateMarker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deactivateMarker(sender:)), for:
                                    .touchUpInside)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(deactivateMarker)
        
        return stackView
    }()
```

Place it inside your source view and hide it (on `viewDidLoad`, for example):

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupMarkersStackView()
    }
    
    private func setupMarkersStackView() {
        sourceView.addSubview(stacmarkersStackViewView)
        markersStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: triggerMarkersBtn.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        markersStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filterSectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        markersStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        markersStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: triggerMarkersBtn.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        markersStackView.isHidden = true
    }
```

Then when `handleMarkers` is called you show it:

```swift
@objc func handleMarkers(sender: UIButton) {
    markersStackView.isHidden = false
}
```

And when inner buttons are tapped you hide it:

```swift
    @objc func activateMarker(sender: UIButton) {
        // do needed things
        markersStackView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    @objc func deactivateMarker(sender: UIButton) {
        // do needed things
        markersStackView.isHidden = true
    }
```